# How to restrict WPForms form submission?

Tags: php, wordpress, wpforms

How can I restrict form submissions for a specific user to a specific time ? For example I want a subscriber can't send more than 10 forms per month or 5 forms per 14 days. How can I limit this ? Maybe there is a php code that can be embedded in CodeSnippets or a plugin ?

Looking for information on the official website